# ArangoDB crashes while arangorestore.exe

Tags: arangodb

[image: ArangoDB logs (info level)]

**To reproduce:**

1. Have corrupted database (I think it's the same-time writing issue for non **waitForSync** collection)
2. Use **arangodump.exe**
3. Use **arangorestore.exe** (Service **arangod.exe** stops working while run)
4. Get **Arangod.exe** crashed after trying to launch the service

To make backup I were ignoring some collection using **--maskings** option and rule set. I have gotten an error if I weren't.
To restore the data I did use stable and also nightly, the latest versions of ArangoDB server.

There is not much useful info for the deeper log level.

Also happens for another *win10* computer. And can't be run on *linux* (wsl debian) because my computer's processor doesn't support **sse 4.2** or higher

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb and provide all the relevant information, including the minidump file mentioned in your console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older version **3.8.5-1** works fine! *(upgraded my previous version 3.8.1)*

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the question but an observation that something apparently broke in a more recent version.  Suggest opening an issue with the maintainers of the software